# Jinja2 can't understand formats on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, sqlite, numpy, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run a basic reporting tool off a Raspberry Pi on my internal network.  To accomplish this, I'm using:

- Raspbian OS
- Flask (Jinja2)
- Pandas to pull from a SQLite db of cached values (via pandas.io)
- Numpy, for data aggregation.

Basically, I have a Flask view that pulls some daily totals (date, visits, video plays, etc.) from a SQLite table, and then aggregates the data by date via NumPy, converts it to a tuple, and then kicks it out to the HTML template.  In the HTML template, I have a Jinja filter that converts dates to a friendlier format, and then it converts any numbers to a comma-separated format for easier reading.

Worked perfectly on my makeshift staging environment (my own laptop—OSX 10.9.5).  But running it on the Raspberry Pi—either remotely via ssh or directly off the Pi—Jinja2 suddenly forgets how to deal with numbers.  On staging, Jinja2 handles numpy.int64 types as a number.  On the Raspberry Pi, it acts like it's some unknown format.

Here's the code I'm using to convert the pandas array to a tuple:

```
data_set = [tuple(x) for x in grand_total.to_records(index = False)]
```

And here's the Jinja template filter I'm using to handle dates.  I added an extra elif to convert numpy.int64 to int in there, but it still didn't work.

```
@app.template_filter('DateFormattr')
def DateFormattr(PossDate):
  if(isinstance(PossDate, numpy.datetime64)):
    PossDate = pandas.to_datetime(PossDate)
    PossDate.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    PossDate = str(PossDate)[0:10]
    return PossDate
  else:
    return PossDate
```

And here's the code to build the actual table:

```
{% for row in the_data %}

<tr>
{% for cell in row %}
 <td> 
  {% if cell is not number  %}
    <b>
    {{ cell | DateFormattr }}
    </b>
  {% else %}
    {% print '{0:,}'.format(cell | int) %}
  {% endif %}
  </td>
```

What's going on here?  Is there a quirk on the Raspberry Pi that makes Flask or the Jinja2 engine go haywire?

There's a lot going on, and I may have missed some details, so feel free to ask for more clarification.

**Edited to add** Relevant packages:

*On the RPi:*

- Flask 0.10.1
- Flask-WTF 0.11
- WTForms 2.0.2
- Jinja2 2.7.3
- numpy 1.8.2
- pandas 0.14.1
- SQLAlchemy 1.0.4

*On the Mac:*

- Flask 0.10.1
- Flask-WTF 0.11
- WTForms 2.0.2
- Jinja2 2.7.3
- numpy 1.9.2
- pandas 0.15.2
- SQLAlchemy 0.9.9

Both are running Python v2.7.9.  (Someday, I'll stop worrying and learn to love Python 3.)

IIRC, I had to use apt-get to install Pandas because of limitations on the RPi, hence the version differences.

Comment: Versions of Python and libraries, etc on both your Pi and Mac?

Comment: What happens when you remove the DateFormattr custom filter?

Comment: @NickWoodhams : It makes the date field (the first column of the table) show an ugly timestamp, but the rest of the table remains unchanged.

Comment: @nathancahill Of course, should've included it.  I'll add it above.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue if you downgrade numpy and pandas on your Mac to the RPi versions?